# %matplotlib inline doesn't work for plots inside a module

Tags: python, matplotlib, inline

having trouble displaying plots in ipython notebook

here is a simplified version of what I do:

```
%matplotlib inline  
import MyPackage  
obj = MyPackage.MyObj()  
obj.display()
```

inside MyPackage:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
class MyObj(object):  
    ......  
    def display(self):  
        plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(DATA_IN_MyObj)
```

return I got:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x5de5b10>
```

thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `plot` command is inside your module, which has its own namespace, you have to append `plt.show()` in order to display the figure.

```
def display(self):  
    plt.scatter(DATA_IN_MyObj)
    plt.show()
```

`plt.figure()` is not necessary.

`%matplotlib inline` is IPython magic that imports many plotting functions and automatically issues `plt.show()` if one of these functions is detected in a cell.

Comment: I actually did that but to no avail, however plt.plot(DATA_IN_MyObj) works.